# How to classify and substitute NaN with a pipeline

Tags: python, dataframe, pipeline

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'hrs': [1, "NaN", 2], 'Department': ["ResearchDevelopment", "NaN", "ResearchDevelopment"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

And I want to use a pipeline in order to classify it as categorical or numerical and predict NaN values as the median in the case of numerical and ignore in the case of categorical.

I have done the following:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV

from sklearn import pipeline

numeric_features = ["hrs"]
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")), ("scaler", StandardScaler())]
)

categorical_features = ["Department"]
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),("OneHotEncoder", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))]
)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("num", numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ("cat", categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
    ]
)
```

But I do not know where is the error, and if I have to call the data frame or not.

No error happens, but the pipeline is not changing anything.

Comment: Where are you transforming data with `ColumnTransformer`?

Comment: I don't actually know because I copied it from a template. What I have to do is use the pipeline in order to substitute NaN and classify the columns into categorical or numerical.